# Search between two dates not working

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have the following code:

```
var q = context.Fuels.AsQueryable();
if (dateEdit1.EditValue != null && dateEdit2.EditValue != null)
{
   q.Where(d => d.FuelDate >= dateEdit1.DateTime && d.FuelDate <= dateEdit2.DateTime);
}
```

and it's working, it will get all rows in table.

but when I'm using this code:

```
if (dateEdit1.EditValue != null && dateEdit2.EditValue != null)
{
     var r = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<Fuel>(String.Format("SELECT * FROM Fuel WHERE FuelDate BETWEEN '{0}' AND '{1}'", 
                 dateEdit1.DateTime.Year + "-" + dateEdit1.DateTime.Month + "-" + dateEdit1.DateTime.Day, 
                 dateEdit2.DateTime.Year + "-" + dateEdit2.DateTime.Month + "-" + dateEdit2.DateTime.Day));
}
```

it's working but I need to use the first way to get relations working.

Any idea what is the problem in the first one?

Comment: What's not working? (i.e show the error...)

Comment: maybe is because of the time part?

Comment: there is no error but the first way using linq, it will get all table rows so search by dates is not working.

Comment: No, It's `Date` field in DB

Comment: see my response, you need to assign it to the var q for it to have any effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside of your if clause, you need to assign it to q, if you don't do that q is just a query for all `Fuels`

This should work:

```
q = q.Where(d => d.FuelDate >= dateEdit1.DateTime && d.FuelDate <= dateEdit2.DateTime);
```